# nodejs - mongoose not throwing an error with a broken Uri

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following code in my index.ts file:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const DBUri = "blah";

const connectDatabase = (): void => {
    try {
        mongoose.connect(DBUri, {useNewUrlParser: true}, () => {
            console.log('mongoose connected.')
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        throw e
    }
};

connectDatabase()
```

When I compile into js and execute the file, I get `mongoose connected` logged into the console. But I would expect an error to be thrown (since the `DBUri` is broken).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find you error or disconnection thru these events

```
try {
      mongoose.connect(DBUri, {useNewUrlParser: true}, () => {
          console.log('mongoose connected.')
      })

       mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => { console.log("Disconnect")  });

       mongoose.connection.on('error', (error) => {
       console.error('[error]: ', error);
      });
    } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    throw e
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be capturing an `error` argument in your callback as per the Mongoose documentation:

```
mongoose.connect(DBUri, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err) => {
  if(err) return console.log('mongoose failed to connect.')
  console.log('mongoose connected.')
});
```

Additionally, your `try..catch` is superfluous since you are already passing error handling to Mongoose via that callback.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#callback